# Is it okay to start a sentence with "There is" especially when concluding a paragraph?

Tags: style, existentials

Is it okay to start a sentence with "There is" especially when concluding a paragraph? Example:

> **There is** a resemblance between the Flashlight song and my parents because they specifically serve as the light and warmth of every home.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify your post, but I had to guess at what you meant. 'When concluding a paragraph' brings its own demands; 'There is' is often used to introduce a new point or focus, but the final sentence of a paragraph should rarely do that.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't see why it couldn't also be used at the end, to express the conclusion. The paragraph could have been describing the Flashlight song, then conclude with this sentence.

Comment: @Barmar My statement is sufficiently hedged to make yours at best  superfluous.

Comment: What do you mean by "okay"? If you are asking about grammar, then yes it is okay. However, if you are asking about style, you should give your reasoning for doubting that it is okay.

Answer (score -2):

A concluding sentence proposes a piece of advise, a future prediction or a recommendation. A concluding sentence is signaled by linkers like ; to conclude, In conclusion

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Please take a closer look at the question. You will see that the OP is not asking what a concluding sentence is or does, but whether "There is" can acceptably introduce a concluding paragraph. Try and edit your answer explaining and providing research for your explanation if possible. I am sad to see the unexplained downvotes to your first ever post on this site.